# laravel show image stored in s3 bucket

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I am having a problem with previewing the image I stored in s3 Right now, I have a bucket that has the image I want to preview to users. The way I am thinking of doing it now is by getting the link of the file I stored, then show it.

Here is the code of the function in the controller:

```
public function showQuestion ()
{
    $tempUrl =  Storage::disk('s3')->url('fileNameIwant.jpg');
    return view('questionList', compact('tempUrl'));
}
```

questionList.blade.php file

```
<div class = "pictureQuestion"><img src="{{ $tempUrl }}"  alt="Image"/> <div>
```

I got access denied error from s3. So from this log, I think I should make the bucket public. So:

1. Is there a way to get the image's URL without setting the bucket public? like adding credential etc ...
2. The reason I don't want to make the bucket public is because then It can be accessed by anybody ? (like random user can access it). Did I understand correctly?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Create another bucker and make it public. This way you don't mix things up. Later, to access it just call the disk method with the name of the public bucker: ```Storage::disk('s3Public')```

Comment: But if I make another bucket and make it public, will the view be able to trace and view all the images in that bucket ?

Comment: You can use a temporaryURL without setting it to public bucket, check this out in the documentation under "Temporary URLs" section: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-urls

Comment: No, the visitors cannot view all images of the bucker. It works more like an unlisted video from Youtube. The URL will be public, but the directory not. Unless you explicitly want to!

Comment: even when I set the bucket to public, I can't access the file. I managed to write a file on the bucket though. Do I have to do extra steps  after setting bucket public ?